# Creating 4 concentric boxes with different background colors – only 2 of them appear

Tags: css

Why can't I show a box within a box, within a box, within a box, with 4 different background colors, 4 different div ids, I don't want to specify a width,  I only see two colors when I should see 4?

Thanks for your help - Matthew

Whey can't I show tags? This is kind of complicated!!!!

Comment: some example code of what you have would be easier if you want us to help

Comment: Can you post the relevant snippet of your code?

Comment: Did you want them to be different size boxes?

Comment: show ur code please and create  a fiddle for us : http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you post the code (and maybe an image of what you're trying to achieve)? There should be no problem giving 4 `div` elements different IDs.

Comment: How do I show tags? The last time I put in tags the editor didn't show them?

Comment: @Matthew use the code button, it looks like this {} or wrap your text in backticks: \`code\`

Comment: You want to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mrmike/cyG8e/ ?

Comment: @Mike Do I need to specify a Height?, can you do a another fiddle with no height?

Comment: @Matthew905 But you need to add padding http://jsfiddle.net/mrmike/cyG8e/1/

Answer (score 2):

A block element will fill out the dimensions of its parent element unless there are explicit widths set or there is padding inside a containing element. So if you have divs inside divs, make sure you have padding in the containing divs set (if you're not going to set explicit widths)

Comment: let's see your html and styles then, so we can see what might be up

Comment: or add margins. that way if you set your text-align to center it will position itself in the center of it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a height. The div could be 0x0 and that's probably not what you want.

Below is an example of what we think you want but I specified a height and width.
http://jsfiddle.net/8T6KG

Update:
As recommended, I removed the width and height:
http://jsfiddle.net/8T6KG/3/

Comment: Even if you remove the width and height values from your jsfiddle you'll still be able to see all the colors as you've added padding.

Comment: Your brilliant! Thanks.  So I need 5 boxes!

Answer (score 1):

you must set some `min-height` and `min-width` style and then you can give proper style each div

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nTfmB/)**

Comment: I can't set min height or min width I need it to just flow around each other

Comment: `min-height` and `min-width` is not necessary; you can go with `padding` and `margin` too.. btw setting those is good practice

Answer (score 0):

can you paste some sample code? plus, you can try setting the position to relative. And I think the outer most div needs to have some height and width set.